# Cannot see dual boot menu

Tags: windows, linux

I installed linux mint 14 a few days ago(With windows XP sp3). And yesterday i uninstalled linux because of low disk space. After uninstall Linux i entered in recovery console and typed "fixmbr". Today i added some disk space and just installed linux mint 14 again with windows xp. But i couldn't see the dual boot option window and windows XP boots normally. Please help me to set the dual boot option. This is the list of my hard drive partitions - 
C - 42GB -installed windows XP
Unknown - 4.9GB - Swap space i added for Linux mint.
F -134 GB- F drive of my windows xp
D -136 GB - D drive of my windowd xp
E -130 GB - E drive of my windows xp
Unknown -15.9 GB - This is where i installed Linux Mint 14

Answer (score 1):

Restore GRUB using an Ubuntu Live CD:

http://www.faqforge.com/linux/restore-grub-bootloader-after-windows-installation-on-multi-boot-system/